# Swift: Auto-Login user with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to auto-login the user if he is already signed and just head to the main view but the code is running twice and you can see the transistion instead of the view just showing. How do I fix it?

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.slideMenuController
    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener {
        auth, user in
        if user != nil {
            // User is signed in.
            print("Automatic Sign In: \(user?.email)")

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EmployeeRevealViewController")
            self.window!.rootViewController = initialViewController

        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Log

```
2016-06-06 01:00:55.585 Untitled[13009:6258910] Configuring the default app.
2016-06-06 01:00:55.657 Untitled[13009:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-06-06 01:00:55.666 Untitled[13009:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2016-06-06 01:00:55.714 Untitled[13009:6258910] Firebase Crash Reporting: Successfully enabled
2016-06-06 01:00:55.739: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-06-06 01:00:55.739: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2016-06-06 01:00:55.760: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.1.0
2016-06-06 01:00:55.781: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-06-06 01:00:55.788 Untitled[13009:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
Automatic Sign In: Optional("mohamed.mohd@hotmail.com")
2016-06-06 01:00:56.759: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> APNS Environment in profile: development
Automatic Sign In: Optional("mohamed.mohd@hotmail.com")
2016-06-06 01:00:57.811 Untitled[13009:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
```

Comment: did you log the auth data ?

Comment: follow this doc from firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#2_implement_google_sign-in

Comment: I have followed that doc. It works, but the code just runs twice as you can see at the end of the log. And then there's a transition from the home screen to the main screen

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing anything auth related in your other VC's?  Whats the transition from home screen to the main screen exactly?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
if let alreadySignedIn = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
    // segue to main view controller
} else {
    // sign in
}
```

Comment: And remember to not put the code in `viewDidLoad()` but rather in `viewDidAppear`. I made that mistake and did not realize why the seque did not go through even though it was called.

Comment: What happens when the user closes and reopens the app?

Answer (score 7):

As for the updated documentation, this is the recommened way to do it based on the Firebase documentation and it worked for me:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
  // User is signed in.
  // ...
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  // ...
}
```

Firebase changed a but their naming convention, most noticably:

**FIRAuth got renamed to Auth**

Also for best results, I put this inside the viewDidAppear() like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with viewDidAppear is that the login page (or whichever page this function is being called on) appears for a microsecond and then the "yourIdentifier" is loaded... is there any solution for that?

Comment: @DragonFire You should start your app on the page that assumes the user is already logged in, and then `if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil`, present the login screen on top.

Answer (score 2):

Without identifier for Firebase 4 and swift 4, it worked fine for me...

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        let newViewController: YourViewController = YourViewController()
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the func "override func viewDidAppear" to instantly log in if user != nil. You also forgot to add "view", use self.**view**.window

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeTabBarVC")
            self.view.window!.rootViewController = initialViewController
        } else { return }
    }
```